# Using slice() but want to use start, and length. Is this possible?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have almost a hundred columns to classify from a mainframe file with no delimits and am using slice functionality to achieve this.  I'm slicing each location into a list, then combining these lists to then create a Pandas dataframe to perform additional analysis on.

```
    a = slice(0,10)
    b = slice(10,25)
```

However, I know the start location, and the length of each string.  Is there a similar way to classify using start and length instead of start and end?

Comment: `slice(start, start + length)`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python

```
>>> x = 'hello world'
>>> start = 6
>>> length = 5
>>> x[start:start+length]
'world'
```

Pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['hello world']})
>>> df['y'] = df['x'].str.slice(start, start+length)
>>> df
             x      y
0  hello world  world
```

Comment: Due to my limited Python, I went  down the list route, but in hindsight what you have above is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `start+length` as the end argument?